# Visual Studio heart overlay in solution explorer. What does it mean?

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-2017

In solution explorer you sometime see heart overlay in the class definition nodes. What does it signify?

Answer (score 33):

I believe you are referring to a signal icon. The heart is shown over types / members when they are internal (C#) or Friend (VB.NET). The meaning of the icons is [documented on Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2017):

- [image] Friend/Internal. Accessible only from the project.

Comment: Kudos.  I have been Googling for that reference for months.

Answer (score 8):

In C# it happens when you assign a value to nullable type.

Example:

```
int? k = null;        //here the symbol for k in the Watch Windows is without heart
k = 5;
```

After the assignment (k = 5) the symbol k will also contain the heart overlay.

I conducted the test using Visual Studio 2017 [visual-studio-2017].

[image]

Comment: That particular case seems to be a bug that was fixed recently. (https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/232694/public-nullable-property-in-public-class-shows-as.html)