# What does the property with heart icon in Visual Studio Watch window means?

Tags: visual-studio

I'm familiar with the property icon in Visual Studio's watch window. But I don't know what is this icon looks like property, but with a heart on it.

Could anybody tell me what does it mean?

[image]

I go to definition of the class, but doesn't find properties with heart defined there. I don't know where does Visual Studio find these properties.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Visual Studio heart overlay in solution explorer. What does it mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18807344/visual-studio-heart-overlay-in-solution-explorer-what-does-it-mean)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This kind of sub-icon mean this is a property only accessible only from the project.

Without the heart mean that it's accessible from anywhere in this component and from any component that references it.

It's "internal" or "public"

As defined here : [Class View and Object Browser icons](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/class-view-and-object-browser-icons?view=vs-2019)